# Flex Framework - How to tell if user is using cached framework?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, framework-caching

I have a public facing application deployed with Flex. I want to switch to using the cached framework (.swz) but need to know if for my user base this is an effective solution or not (most users will only visit the site once and its just not worth it).

What I want to do is track whether or not a user has loaded the .swz/.swf file during that session - or if they are using a cached version they had previously downloaded from me or another site. If say 80% of users are downloading the framework .swz then i may as well embed the cutdown framework. But if 60% of users already have the framework I'd rather allow that cached version to be used.

The best solution I have now is to look at the web server log and count the .swz file downloads vs. the number of times my main application .swf file is loaded. This is clumsy and a pain and I havent even been able to go to the effort of doing it yet.

I cannot seem to find anything indicating what .swz or .swf files are loaded. I'd like to track against the current user session if i can determine this.

Answer (score 3):

My advice is to use the cached framework regardless of your user-base.  The fact is, you won't be alone in doing so and it will only be a matter of time before it pays off (even if it is on return visits).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the solution you want, but just to help you with the log parsing, you can use this to get counts for each from the logs (assuming you're on a linux server) :

```
grep -c \.swz web_log_dir/* 
grep -c \.swf web_log_dir/*
```